# Removing iframe tag from feed output

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I need to remove an iframe tag that is causing my feed not to work. Here is the url of the validator [VALIDATOR](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://www.naturalnigerian.com/feed/). The url of the feed is [Natural Nigerian Feed](http://naturalnigerian.com/feed). Please could someone tell me what to do. It's been very frustrating. Here is the code I have written to handle it but it is not working
`function rss_noiframe($content) {
      // filter out iframe here
    $content =  preg_replace( '/<iframe(.*)/iframe>/is', '', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_noiframe');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_noiframe');
add_filter('the_content_rss', 'rss_noiframe');` 
I put this code inside the template's function.php but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

this should replace all iframes (upper and lower case)

```
function rss_noiframe($content) {
      // filter out iframe here
    $content =  preg_replace( '@<iframe[^>]*?>.*?</iframe>@siu', '', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. the iframe still appears. Where is the best place to put this function I have written?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me -

```
$string = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?\/iframe>/i','', $originalString);
```

:)